# Cannot publish app to PlayStore - It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions

Tags: android, google-play-services

[image: Play Store Snap]

I am unable to understand the error. What I understood is that in my 14th version targetSdkVersion was 23 and now I am unable to upload the apk.
I now have targetSdkVersion = 22 and even for my previous version targetSdkVersion was 22.

I want to launch the app asap. But stuck with this problem.

Gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "***"
    versionCode 30
    versionName "3.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.1.1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have uploaded an APK to prod that uses the M runtime permissions model (level 23);  This means that you can't downgrade to 22.  This is due to the changed permissions model between these different versions.

To be clear, you won't be able to distribute your APK targeting API 22 again, and there is not a way to change this.

Comment: But my current live version has target API as 22. Correct me if I am wrong, we can publish the app targeting the same or higher API?
But in my case, I am targeting the same API level. What wrong am I doing?