# forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-studio-2.1

Problem to publish app as Beta version i can upload and save as draft. Play store show me this error after release Save as draft.

> It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from version 28 (target SDK 23) to version 25 (target SDK 21).

But i didn't change my gradle at all. I just update my android studio with latest one. please help to fix this issue.

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 29
            versionName '1.12.5'
            multiDexEnabled = true

        }
```

Comment: What is your previous live build  `targetSdkVersion` ? was it 22 ?

Comment: Related --> [Cannot publish app to PlayStore - It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416514/cannot-publish-app-to-playstore-it-is-forbidden-to-downgrade-devices-which-pre?rq=1)

Comment: Usually this issue happens when you have submitted an app with targetsdk version 23 and for next upgrade you change the targetsdk to 22 or below.

Comment: last build of targetSdkVersion as beta release was 23

Comment: @Sunil i didn't downgrade target sdk in latest build i use target sdk 23

Comment: May be this can help you. seems to be the same issue https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Android-developers/dpK2XO025kQ